# Why is bottom-alligned UITextView getting 0 height when using autolayout for UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I am using autolayout for my UITableViewCell and my UITextView is getting zero height. It has the correct height in willDisplayCell but it becomes zero when cell is actually displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is that auto-layout is half-baked.

It takes over, discards the position and size settings of your view hierarchy, and generates size and position values based on it's rules. It has an annoying tendency to collapse views to zero height. Thus you need to explicitly add height constraints that prevent this from happening.

I am forcing myself to use auto-layout, and trying to like it. So far I dislike it pretty intensely.  It makes form design in IB a great deal harder, and makes it very hard to track down problems when something goes wrong.

Comment: My textview doesn't have fixed height. Is there a way to have a dynamic height? I am assuming dynamic height wont be possible with height constraint.

Comment: No, it can. You should create a height constraint, and then control-drag from the constraint onto your view controller to create an outlet that points to the constraint. You can then change the constraint's setting through code.

Comment: You can also set minimum and maximum height constraints. I would start with a minimum height constraint so it can't collapse completely.

Comment: Ok, what's with the drive-by down vote? If you think my answer is less than satisfactory, explain why.